# Differentiate a Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Given the **Differential equation** $y'=-2xy^{2}$.

**Find the derivative** $\frac{d(y')}{dx}$!

**My approach**, which is **not correct** according to **Wolfram Alpha**:

1. Plugging in: $\frac{d(y')}{dx}=\frac{d(-2xy^{2})}{dx}$
2. Pulling out constants #1:$-2\cdot\frac{d(x^{1}\cdot y^{2})}{dx}$
3. Pulling out constants #2:$-2\cdot y^{2}\cdot\frac{d(x^{1})}{dx}$
4. Do the differential: $-2\cdot y^{2}\cdot1=\frac{d(y')}{dx}$

Wolfram Alpha computes this:
$\frac{d(y')}{dx}=-4x\cdot y\cdot y'(x)-2y^{2}$

Since i do not have the Pro-Version of Wolfram Alpha and i am curious of knowing the maths behind it: **What steps happen here and why can't i do it in my way ?**

---

### Background info:

I want to find those Derivatives in order to compute a numerical approximation for the Differential equation using a Taylor series expansion of 4th order.

---

### Edits (after comments and answers were given):

So by the product rule, stated as follows:

$\left(f(x)\cdot g(x)\right)^{'}=f'(x)\cdot g(x)+f(x)\cdot g'(x)$

I identified the following terms as the elements of that product rule:

- $f(x)=x$
- $g(x)=\left(y(x)\right)^{2}=y(x)\cdot y(x)$ (the product rule has to be applied here a second time)
- $f'(x)=1$
- $g'(x)=y'(x)\cdot y(x)+y(x)\cdot y'(x)$
- $\left(f(x)\cdot g(x)\right)^{'}=f'(x)\cdot g(x)+f(x)\cdot g'(x)$
- $\left(f(x)\cdot g(x)\right)^{'}=1\cdot\left(y(x)\right)^{2}+x\cdot\left(y'(x)\cdot y(x)+y(x)\cdot y'(x)\right)$
- $\left(f(x)\cdot g(x)\right)^{'}=\left(y(x)\right)^{2}+2\cdot x\cdot y'(x)\cdot y(x)$

Comment: going from $2$ to $2,$ you cant pull the $y$ out as if it were constant. $(xy^2)' = y^2 + 2xyy'$

Comment: very well presented question +1.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that $y$ is not a constant, it is a function of $x$.  Therefore you have to use the product rule between $x$ and $y^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the product rule, but i cannot find out how to solve the product rule for a squared function. Could you provide explicit written steps ?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} y^2 = 2 y \frac{dy}{dx}$ by the chain rule.

Comment: @kiltek your work in your edit looks good to me, although I'd comment that you use the product rule in both places you say "chain rule".  Do you see that your work then would give the answer that Wolfram gave?  Don't forget the $-2$.

Answer (score 2):

> Pulling out constants #2:$-2\cdot y^{2}\cdot\frac{d(x^{1})}{dx}$

Nope that's wrong, you had in step 2, $$-2\frac{d(x^{1}\cdot y^{2})}{dx}$$
which can be expanded by **product rule** as $$-2y^{2}\frac{d(x^{1})}{dx}-2x^1\frac{d(y^{2})}{dx}$$
Now that's, $$-2y^{2}1x^0-2x^1\frac{d(y^{2})}{dy}.\frac{y}{x}=2y^2-2x.2y.y'=2y^2-4xy(-2xy^2)=2y^2+8x^2y^3$$ by **chain rule** and **substitution**. The reason being y is a **dependent variable**, yes a **variable**.